# Why after drawing circles their colors change?

Tags: c#, winforms, picturebox

Why after drawing circles their colors change? , in fact, I draw circles but my problem is that after every time double click, the color of next circles change from blue to the background color.

```
public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        pictureBox1.Paint += new PaintEventHandler(pic_Paint);
    }

    public Point positionCursor { get; set; }
    private List<Point> points = new List<Point>();
    public int circleNumber { get; set; }

    private void pictureBox1_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        positionCursor = this.PointToClient(new Point(Cursor.Position.X - 25, Cursor.Position.Y - 25));

        points.Add(positionCursor);

        pictureBox1.Invalidate();
    }

    private void pic_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        Graphics g = e.Graphics;
        g.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;

        foreach (Point pt in points)
        {
            Pen p = new Pen(Color.Tomato, 2);

            g.FillEllipse(Brushes.Blue, positionCursor.X, positionCursor.Y, 20, 20);

            g.DrawEllipse(p, pt.X, pt.Y, 20, 20);

            p.Dispose();
        }
    }
```

[image]

Comment: Create the pen outside the loop, in a [using](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/yh598w02.aspx) statement. For example `using (var pen = new Pen(Color.Tomato, 2){ /* Rest of Code*/ }`. The `using` statement calls the `Dispose` method on the object in the correct way, and (when you use it as shown earlier) it also causes the object itself to go out of scope as soon as `Dispose` is called. Within the `using` block, the object is read-only and cannot be modified or reassigned.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're drawing the ellipses correctly, but you always fill only one of them (the last one added, at the cursor's position).

```
// This is ok
g.DrawEllipse(p, pt.X, pt.Y, 20, 20);

// You should use pt.X and pt.Y here
g.FillEllipse(Brushes.Blue, positionCursor.X, positionCursor.Y, 20, 20);
```

Answer (score 0):

change pic_Paint as below

```
 private void pic_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            Graphics g = e.Graphics;
            g.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;

            foreach (Point pt in points)
            {
                Pen p = new Pen(Color.Tomato, 2);
                g.DrawEllipse(p, pt.X, pt.Y, 20, 20);
                g.FillEllipse(Brushes.Blue, pt.X, pt.Y, 20, 20);
                p.Dispose();
            }

        }
```

Comment: Why create a new pen for each point? Why not use the same pen.